# PHP Type Casting a string to interger

Tags: php, casting

I am parsing a file and pulling data out of it. One of the pieces of data is a decimal such as 1.9.

For some reason when I tried to save to my MySQL table it kept saving as 0. The field type is Decimal (6,2) in the table.

I attempted to manually cast it using various php functions such as...

settype(), (int), (float), (double) etc. Everytime I cast it, it would set it to zero or boolean. I used gettype to check it.

When parsing it I used trim() and str_replace() functions to remove spaces. What is odd is that I am using same method for pulling other values/decimals out of same file and php handled the casing itself.

Any ideas what could possible prevent me from casting this as a a number?

Comment: `floatval` should do what you need http://php.net/manual/en/function.floatval.php

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I did attempt that and it still set it to zero. I guess there was still some character attached to that preventing those functions to work. I ended up using this to clear out all characters. $dim = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $dim) - This seemed to fix the issue. Not sure its the most efficient way to handle this but it worked for now. Not that familiar with using regular expressions. Thanks for your suggestion though.

Answer (score 1):

So this is what solved my problem for anyone who runs into this situation. Not sure it is the best way to handle it but it worked.

```
$dim = preg_replace("/[^0-9.]/", "", $dim)
```